# What parts of the service do you say when late to Shacharit?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, shulchan-aruch, arriving-late

*According to the Shulchan Aruch (please cite Saeef and Siman so I can read further):*

What should one do when he's late to Shachrit? What should he skip and what must he say?

Comment: If you read the back of artscroll siddur you question will be answered

Comment: @sam No, it will receive one answer. Other opinions exist besides Rabbi Scroll's.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44855/5323

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shulchan Aruch OC 52](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%91) says to say Baruch she'amar, Ashrei, 2 of the הללו's, yishtabach and berchos kerias shema:

> אם בא לבית הכנסת ומצא צבור בסוף פסוקי דזמרה אומר ברוך שאמר עד מהולל
>   בתשבחות ואחר כך תהלה לדוד עד מעתה ועד עולם הללויה. ואחר כך הללו את ה'
>   מן השמים עד לבני ישראל עם קרובו הללויה. ואחר כך הללו אל בקדשו עד כל
>   הנשמה תהלל יה. ואחר כך ישתבח ואחר כך ישתבח ואחר כך יוצר וקריאת שמע
>   וברכותיה ויתפלל עם הצבור ואם אין שהות כל כך ידלג גם מזמור הללו את ה'
>   מן השמים.

C.f. [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Someone_who_comes_late_to_Davening)

More Info:
The goal is to say shemoneh esrei with the tzibbur. 
You need to say birchos kerias shema no matter what. 
Based on your time, you should try to say:

1. Baruch she'amar Ashrei and Yishtabach
2. 2 of the הללו's
3. The rest of the
   הללו's
4. 'הודו לה (Rema)
5. etc.

Also, you should say Berachos at the beginning, though if there isn't even time for that, you can just say birchos hatorah and e-lohai neshama before and the rest after.

Comment: This is incomplete. He also allows skipping all of Pesukei Dezimra if really late.

Comment: That's what the links are for, but I added clarification.

Comment: Not sure what you are holding back for. Just summarize the rules. It'll take you one paragraph.

Comment: ok, since u insist..

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch mentions that you must say Elohai Netzor beforehand? I'm pretty sure that was made up by the Peri Megadim.

Comment: Also, for the Rama and the Gra it would seem that you don't have to say Birchos Hatorah either. Even for the Mechaber it's only a Chumra to do so.