# Order of importance for the chapters of Pesukei Dizimra for someone that arrives late to Synagogue.

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, pesukei-dezimra

What is the exact order of importance of the different parts of Pizukei Dizimra when someone arrives late for Shacharit?

I am looking for something like the following:

Priority #1: Baruch Sheamar & Yistahach

Priority #2: Ahrey
...

It would help if you could also provide the reason why each part is in that priority level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What parts of the service do you say when late to Shacharit?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/what-parts-of-the-service-do-you-say-when-late-to-shacharit)

Comment: @Daniel Although that question asks specifically according to the Shulchan Aruch - perhaps it should be closed as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the entire Pesukei Dezimra can be skipped (Start with Birchas Krias Shema). Because the purpose of Pesukei Dezimra is to make the Tefilah desirable to Hashem, and praying with a Minyan accomplishes this more.

If there is time, add in Baruch Sheamar, the whole Ashrei*, and Yishtabach, because the Chachamim established the Pesukei DeZimra around Chapter 145 of Tehillim (even though the original Takana was from chapter 145 to the end of Tehillim), so doing that is a bare minimum Pesukei Dezimra.

What follows in an order of priority addition. The intention is to say the relevant passages in their proper relative order.

If there is time, add הללו אל בקדשו‏ (Tehillim 150)

If there is time, add הללו את ה' מן השמים‏ (Tehillim 148)

If there is time, say all 6 of the last chapters of Tehillim (so add in the missing three from above). The goal here being to get to the main Takanas Chachamim.

For what follows the idea is to add whole sections that are quoted over collections of verses.

If there is more time, add ויברך דוד until לשם תפארתך

Next, For those who say Hodu after Baruch Sheamar, then הודו לה' קראו until והוא רחום and then skip to the והוא רחום that is before Ashrei.

The source for the above is [Shulchan Aruch HaRav O.C. 52](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/6/52/index.htm)

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([13](http://www.kitzur.net/main.php?siman=14):7) adds in some considerations for Shabbos and Yom Tov, which are not really discussed in earlier Poskim, AFAIK, and concludes:

> ואם רואה שאפלו אם יתחיל בברכת יוצר אור לא יוכל להתפלל שמונה-עשרה עם הצבור אלא אם כן ימהר, טוב לו יותר להתפלל בפני עצמו כסדר במתינות ובכונה
>
> If he sees that even if he [skips all of the above and] starts with [the Brachos before Krias Shma of] Yotzeir he will not be able to daven Shemona Esrei unless he hurries through the davening, it is better to daven to himself [without saying Shemona Esrei with the Minayn] in order [i.e. say everything] unhurried and with proper concentration.

<sup>* I'm using that term loosely - the actual chapter 145 of Tehillim is what matters, the extra two verses before and one after can be skipped.</sup>

Comment: if one really has time only for ashrei shouldn't one say that, skipping baruch she'amar and yishtabach being that they were only brachos nisaken on pisukei dizimra? Ashrei due the passuk of pose'ach es yadecha is the absolute apex. And stands on its own accord.

Comment: @ Yishai Also in your footnote you mention the idea of not including the opening and closing psukim of Ashrei. However logical this is, do you have a source? It seems that tefila is referred to as both ashrei and tehila lidovid interchangeably from talmud to shulchan aruch so I would be a little uncomfortable putting ashrei on the guest bed in Sodom to chop off the ends till I had a source.

Comment: @user6591 Doesn't the gemara say it's said because of aleph beis acrostic and pose'ach es yadecha?  So that would imply like Yishai said. (Unless I am misapplying that point)

Comment: @ Yez good point but by that logic we can chop off the first passuk of tehila etc. And while this isn't really a good argument on my part, an addendum is not comparable to the main body of the psalm, I would still like a source to be able to trim around the edges that seem to have ancient origin.

Comment: @user6591, The Kitzur says to do the chopping explicitly. Regarding Ashrei alone without the brachos, maybe there is a point to it (מתוך שמחה), but it isn't in poskim, and it isn't Pesukei DeZimra without the Brachos, really.

Comment: @ Yishai. Nice Kitzur, thanks. Back to ashrei without brachos, the thing thats bothering me is that saying ashrei is from the gemara. Not necessarily in the context of psukei dizimra, but at least to say it. Now if we assume that baruch she'amar fell from the sky during the time of the geonim, and yishtabach was formed based on az yashir, or whatever opinion of their origin we would go with, doesn't ashrei end up on a different playing field?

Comment: @user6591, as you said "not necessarily in the context of psukei dizimra", so you can make it up afterwards, as you are supposed to anyway. BTW, it is not at all clear that the brachos are from after the Gemara. See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=13769&rid=610).

Comment: @Yishai .another good point. Yeah, I've seen mentioned that they are from the times of chazzal, its just always been hard for me to swallow. Is it possible that there would be no mention at all in any sugya anywhere if they were really that ancient?

Comment: @Yishai back to the passuk ashrei. I just peeked in the tur. The reason for the minhag to say it before ashrei is because we learn from there to wait a 'sha'ah' before praying! Pretty funny for the late guy who barely has time to say anything to say!

Comment: @user6591, The Jews of Kaifeng ([p.64 here](http://chaimsimons.net/Kaifeng.pdf)) have it, so I'm comfortable with the idea that it is of ancient origin (if the Rambam and the Rif weren't enough on their own, which I think they are). In any event, we don't have all of the sugyas that were written. Some of the Yerushalmi is known to be missing, and we know there are things in what we do have of the Yerushalmi which don't exist in the Bavli.