# Skipping parts of pessukei dezimroh to get to work on time?

Tags: halacha, time, employment, pesukei-dezimra

Kitzur shulchan aruch states that if a person is afraid of being late to recite shmonei esreh with minyan, it is allowed to skip some parts of the pessukei dezimroh... Does this apply to a person that may be late for his job?

Comment: For what parts to skip (and retain) see: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28606/3483 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44857/3483 but these do not address the part of the question of whether getting to work on time is sufficient reason.

Answer (score 2):

The second link above has the list of priorities and parts one can skip if late, in order to sync with the rest of the mynian. **But** my understanding was always that one has to make up the missing parts by reciting them later alone (this is also mentioned in the Artscroll Siddur in the laws section #30).

Applying this to someone late for a job would mean he can/should recite them later on, e.g., on the way to the job or during a break.

Finally, artscroll mentions (#32) that this only an emergency solution and shouldn't be relied to arrive late as the order of prayers is of utmost importance.

Answer (score 0):

When we were learning the halachos in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch about skipping parts of Pesukei D'Zimra, one of my shiurmates had asked about if he came late to Yeshiva and didn't want to miss more of seder than he had to, if that was a sufficient reason to skip everything except Ashrei and the two bookend brachos. My Rebbe paskened that it was. (My Rebbe's a talmid of Ner Yisrael, if that changes anything.) In theory, that s'vara should apply to any crunch for time, including being late for work. (I believe my father had asked this sha'alah to the Rav of my community, also a talmid of Ner Yisrael, and he said the same thing.)