# (When) should skipped parts of davening be made up?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, time, shacharis-morning-prayer, arriving-late

If someone [skips parts of shacharit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28594/what-parts-of-the-service-do-you-say-when-late-to-shacharit) in order to say shemoneh esrei with the congregation, (when) should the skipped paragraphs be made up?

Comment: I have a distinct memory from when I was in yeshiva of one of my rabbis quoting someone as saying something to the effect of saying pesukei dezimra out of order is like putting your cloths on out of order and consequently if you had to skip part of it, you don't say it later. It would be like putting your underwear on over your pants. Unfortunately I don't remember who he was quoting.

Comment: @Daniel cute, he might have made it up himself. Though the order itself isn't agreed upon by everyone (like mustache ashkenaz vs. sefard/mizrachi regarding placement of Baruch sheamar and the rambam putting shiras hayam after yishtabach)

Comment: @Matt I don't think he made it up himself (although the part about underwear might have been his own editorializing). You're right that different nusachim put pesukei dezimra in different orders and I don't know how to answer that although it doesn't necessarily contradict this idea.

Comment: @Daniel I at least found a posek who thinks (based on Kabbalah) that the order of pesukei dezimra is of crucial enough importance to trump almost anything else: kaf hachayim 52:2

Comment: @Daniel I remember my rebbi saying something similar, though he said that it's not nice to say pesukei dzimra after shmonah esrei -- "Can I have something? Oh, You're so nice...." ....it's more polite to have the שבח first, before the בקשה.

Comment: @Shokhet see Maharal in Nesiv HaAvodah ch. 12 (this is also his objection to saying shir hakavod at the end of davening)

Comment: @Matt Saw that in the end of your answer, +1 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the berachos upon pesukei dezimra (Yishtabach and Baruch Sheamar) cannot be made after one has said the Amidah (Shulchan Aruch 52). The question, then, is about the pesukim/mizmorim.

The Shulchan Aruch there writes that one may, after finishing davening, go back to say the parts of pesukei dezimra that he skipped, and it sounds a bit like he feels that this is the proper thing to do. This also seems to be the position of the Mishna Berurah (52:9). The Aruch Hashulchan (52:4), though, believes that according to the Shulchan Aruch this is merely optional. There doesn't seem to be a time limit, as the Shulchan Aruch's reasoning is that saying pesukei dezimra is no different than saying tehillim, which can be said at any time.

However, the Aruch Hashulchan himself (52:5) believes that one is prohibited from saying pesukei dezimra after prayer, and he insists that this is the position of the Tur and geonim. His reasoning is that "pesukei dezimra was only established for pre-prayer" (in addition to kabalistic reasons). Another reason may also be that it's improper to praise God after praying to Him (see Maharal in Nesiv Ha'Avodah ch. 12 based on Megillah daf 18a)

Comment: That Mishnah Berurah doesn't say anything relevant here. He's discussing birkos hashachar, which you didn't discuss in your answer (although it would have been pertinent to the question asked).

Answer (score 0):

In shulchan aruch siman nun beis it says "**afterwards** you should say the psukei dizimra without the brocho before and brochoh after (meaning boruch sheomar and yishtabach) - (see shulchan aruch harav there where he explains why you don't say the brochos -)  there are two opinions whether you should say it after davening or not therefore the halachah is to say it without the brocohos see also mishnah brurah ois tes where he uses the words ואחר התפלה and after davening...

So you say it after you finish davening.

But see mishnah brurah and others on this who say that there is a custom to not skip any part of davening even for the benefit of tifilah bitzibur.
See also igros kodesh of the lubavitcer rebbe cheilek yud ches page pay aleph who writes that there are those who are against skipping davening even to daven shmonah esrei with the minyan (even if you came on time and the minyan is davening too fast for you).