# On what authority do Lubavitchers not skip when late to shacharis?

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, chabad, tzibur-community, arriving-late

The *Rav*'s *Shulchan Aruch*, *OC* 52, clearly states that, because saying *amida* (*sh'mone esre*) with a congregation is so important, one who arrives late to a congregational *shacharis* service should skip earlier portions of the prayers in order to say *amida* with the congregation. He should even, if necessary to reach *amida* in time, skip almost all of the prayers before *Yotzer*.

Yet I don't see Chabad-Lubavitch folks (well, men), who I'd think would follow the *Rav*, doing so. In my experience, Lubavitch latecomers pray without skipping, even if skipping would enable them to say *amida* with the congregation.

Is there some authority they rely on for this practice? (Does, perhaps, the *Rav* elsewhere (e.g., in his notes on the *sidur*) or one of the later Lubavitch rebbes say to practice thus?)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47472/440

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13715/falling-behind-during-davening

Comment: Also, though not a Lubavitch source, see Note 11 to [this page](https://www.ou.org/torah/machshava/tzarich-iyun/tzarich_iyun_davening_with_a_minyan/): *"... Nonetheless, there are those who advise reciting all of davening in order (Sha’arei Teshuvah 52:1 in the name of Yosef Ometz). It is reported that many great people acted in such a manner (Kaf Hachaim 52:2). ..."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping up with fast davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10268/keeping-up-with-fast-davening)

Comment: @sabbahillel, I don't see how, at all. The other question asks how to keep up with a communal service; this asks on what authority Lubavitchers don't skip prayers. Two completely different questions as far as I can tell (though obviously both are about one's prayer's coinciding with the communal service). Could you explain your comment, please?

Answer (score 1):

Letter from the Lubavitcher Rebbe stating not to skip Pesukei DeZimrah even if you are late.

Comment: Hi EliyahuBenYosef, welcome to Mi Yodeya! If you could specify which letter you are referring to, or even better - link to it, that would greatly improve your answer. As it is, it's not very useful. I hope to see you around the site!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10442/603